# MS Word: When combining documents I get unintended redundancies like "TheTheThe"

Tags: microsoft-word, combine

**The situation:** I have to combine multiple documents with comments and edits from several reviewers.

**The method:** Using MS Word's combine feature (not 'compare')

**The problem:** I get multiple instances of redundant words. For example, I find 'TheTheThe' where there should be only one 'The'; or 'ononon' instead of 'on'. This happens in the beginning and the middle of sentences, in paragraphs, in headings and even in figure titles. To me it seems random and it affects about every 400th word (just a guess). If I combine multiple version of the document, the same words seem to repeat that behavior, so that it is TheThe after the first instance and TheTheThe after the second. I cannot seem to find the common element of the affected words and do not see what else I could do differently to avoid it.

**My questions:** How to avoid these redundancies? Since I will have to do this multiple times and the document is >100 pages, I would like to avoid what goes wrong rather than correct it.

**My thanks:** To you, wonderful person with a helpful answer.

Comment: Interesting problem, but there isn't much to go on.  A quick Google search didn't indicate this is a common problem.  It obviously isn't supposed to do that, which means something isn't working the way it should.  So this isn't the kind of question where there's a clear, definitive answer, like the correct way to use some feature.  It's more likely that something has been corrupted.  Unless somebody has run into this same corruption, people will just be guessing.  Try to distinguish whether it's related to the documents (maybe a common corrupted template), or Word.  Try reinstalling Word.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You seem to have found the same as I have. Unfortunately I cannot find the distinguishing feature of the problem. Reinstalling Word probably will not help since my colleagues have the same problem with the same kind of document (which unfortunately I cannot share since it is privileged information).

Comment: That sounds like it's document related.  See if you can replicate it by creating a similar new document on another machine using a fresh template.

Comment: Are the redundancies itself displayed as changes/revisions/edits/markups?